# Linq from multiple Foreach

Tags: c#, linq

How would I convert the following multiple `foreach` to LINQ?

```
    foreach (var resourceOne in resourceList)
    {
        string s = (string)resourceOne;
        foreach (Control c in gridBtn.Children)
        {
            if (c.GetType() == typeof(ToggleButton))
            {
                int TagPlusOne = Convert.ToInt32(c.Tag) + 1;
                string PaddedResult = TagPlusOne.ToString().PadLeft(3, '0');
                if (PaddedResult == s)
                {
                    ((ToggleButton)c).BorderBrush = Brushes.Red;
                    ((ToggleButton)c).BorderThickness = new Thickness(3, 3, 3, 3);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, you'll need a `foreach` or similar to set the properties on your buttons as LINQ is for *querying* your data (generally side-effect free), not mutating them. However, you can use LINQ to simplify *finding* the buttons you want to edit. e.g. your code could boil down to:

```
var targetButtons = gridBtn
    .Children
    .OfType<ToggleButton>()
    .Where(tb => resourceList.OfType<string>().Contains($"{Convert.ToInt32(tb.Tag) + 1}:D3"));

foreach(var btn in targetButtons)
{
    btn.BorderBrush = Brushes.Red;
    btn.BorderThickness = new Thickness(3, 3, 3, 3);
}
```

Which can be further tweaked/optimized/refactored. Note I've replaced `PadLeft(3, '0')` with the `D3` standard number format string which does the same thing.

Comment: somehow $"{Convert.ToInt32(tb.Tag) + 1}:D3") does not work for my WPF . due to $ not recognized  . i use my original code padleft and it works . thanks

Comment: @LohZhiCheng `$"..."` is an [interpolated string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated) which is similar to `string.Format`. It's a C# 6 feature. If it's not available then you're probably using an older version of C#.

Answer (score 2):

You can't really, however you could simply it by using `Where` and `OfType`:

```
foreach (var in gridBtn.Children.OfType<ToggleButton>)
{
    int TagPlusOne = Convert.ToInt32(c.Tag) + 1;
    string PaddedResult = TagPlusOne.ToString().PadLeft(3, '0');
    foreach (var resourceOne in resourceList.Where(x => x == PaddedResult))
    {
        c.BorderBrush = Brushes.Red;
        c.BorderThickness = new Thickness(3, 3, 3, 3);
    }
}
```

**Disclaimer**: totally untested.

Answer (score 2):

```
IEnumerable<ToggleButton> query =
  from c in gridBtn.Children
  where c.GetType() == typeof(ToggleButton)
  let tagPlusOne = Convert.ToInt32(c.Tag) + 1
  let paddedResult = tagPlusOne.ToString().PadLeft(3, '0')
  join s in resourceList.Cast<string>() on paddedResult equals s
  select c;


foreach(ToggleButton button in query)
{
  button.BorderBrush = Brushes.Red;
  button.BorderThickness = new Thickness(3, 3, 3, 3);
}
```

Comment: Upvoted as its more inline with the spirit of the question

Comment: Ok this is actually way better

Comment: any idea on following error :
Could not find any implementation of the query pattern for source type "UIElement Collection" .Where is not found  . 
gridBtn Actually its my wpf Grid control

Comment: You could call OfType<ToggleButton> if gridBtn.Children does not implement IEnumerable<T>

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this (I couldn't test it though, as I don't have your environment):

```
gridBtn.Children.Where(c =>
        c.GetType() == typeof(ToggleButton) && resourceList.Any(resourceOne =>
            (string) resourceOne ==
            Convert.ToInt32(c.Tag) + 1.ToString().PadLeft(3, '0')))
    .ToList().ForEach(c =>
    {
        ((ToggleButton) c).BorderBrush = Brushes.Red;
        ((ToggleButton) c).BorderThickness = new Thickness(3, 3, 3, 3);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use this code. I tested a code like this for Buttons and WinForm.
I hope the code helps you, in your case.

```
resourceList.Where(resourceOne =>
        {
            string s = (string)resourceOne;
            gridBtn.Children.OfType<ToggleButton>().Where(c =>
            {
                var TagPlusOne = Convert.ToInt32(c.Tag) + 1;
                var PaddedResult = TagPlusOne.ToString().PadLeft(3, '0');
                return PaddedResult == s;
            }).ToList().ForEach(c =>
            {
                c.BorderBrush = Brushes.Red;
                c.BorderThickness = new Thickness(3, 3, 3, 3);
            });
            return true;
        });
```

I think you could use Select instead of Foreach aswell.

```
esourceList.Where(resourceOne =>
        {
            string s = (string)resourceOne;
            var enumerable = ActiveForm.Controls.OfType<Button>().Where(control =>
            {
                var TagPlusOne = Convert.ToInt32(control.Tag) + 1;
                var PaddedResult = TagPlusOne.ToString().PadLeft(3, '0');
                return PaddedResult == s;
            }).Select(control =>
            {
                control.BackColor = Color.Aqua;
                control.Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor;
                return control;
            });
            return true;
        });
```

Comment: thanks i already found the workable answer above with simplified code . thanks again